# Condensing phyloxml phylogenetic trees

Tags: tree, biopython, phylogeny

I am trying to condense (simplifying clades in which all leaves have the same label) phylogenetic trees that are in the phyloxml format. A program called Newick Utils is very useful to do this with newick format trees, condensing this tree:

[Original Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjCEn.png)

into this one:

[Condensed tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WxGi.png)

As I am eventually trying to split my gene tree into all it's subtrees at each duplication node, this is a useful way of reducing the number of subtrees without losing information.

Does anyone know a way of doing this with phyloxml trees? Newick Utils only accepts Newick format, so I need a way to parse the phyloxml format using Biopython. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick answer, you can transform phyloxml into newick very easily:

```
from Bio import Phylo

Phylo.convert("original.xml", "phyloxml", "converted.newick", "newick")
```

Now you can call your Newick Utils to condense the tree.

---

If you want to delete the leafs when they have the same name:

```
for clade in tree.find_clades():
    if clade.count_terminals() > 1:
        leafs = clade.get_terminals()
        if len(set([t.name for t in leafs])) == 1:
            # All the leafs in this clade have the same name.
            #  Cut them all except the first one.
            for leaf in leafs[1:]:                               
                tree.prune(leaf)
```

Ideally you will put the above code in a function that returns the new pruned tree, and call the function every time a leaf is pruned.

Comment: I did try converting to Newick (admittedly using archaeopteryx rather than biopython) but ended up losing a lot of information when I converted back to phyloxml (which I need my trees in for the subtree splitting process). Most importantly, I lost the "Event" tags, which indicate whether speciation or duplication has occured. As this is the basis of how I am splitting my tree (using if clades.events.duplication), I figure this wouldn't be an ideal solution in this instance?

Comment: @spiral01, check out the addition to the answer.